# Overload Resolution in a Namespace

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I am attempting to call an overloaded function inside a namespace and am struggling a bit.

**Working Example 1: No namespace**

```
class C {};

inline void overloaded(int) {}

template<typename T> void try_it(T value) {
  overloaded(value);
}

inline void overloaded(C) {}


int main()
{
  try_it(1);
  C c;
  try_it(c);
  return 0;
}
```

**Working Example 2: All overloads defined before template**

```
class C {};

namespace n {
  inline void overloaded(int) {}
  inline void overloaded(C) {}
}

template<typename T> void try_it(T value) {
  n::overloaded(value);
}

int main()
{
  try_it(1);
  C c;
  try_it(c);
  return 0;
}
```

**Broken Example 3: Some overloads after the template**

```
class C {};

namespace n {
  inline void overloaded(int) {}
}

template<typename T> void try_it(T value) {
  n::overloaded(value);
}

namespace n {
  inline void overloaded(C) {}
}

int main()
{
  try_it(1);
  C c;
  try_it(c); // /tmp/test.cpp: In function ‘void try_it(T) [with T = C]’:
             // /tmp/test.cpp:19:15:   instantiated from here
             // /tmp/test.cpp:8:7: error: cannot convert ‘C’ to ‘int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void n::overloaded(int)’

  return 0;
}
```

Why is this the case? What do I need to do to be able to declare or define an overload after the template function?

Comment: What if you declared them before the template, and implemented them after?

Comment: Same error as case #3 - Note that the declaration for the second was still after the template. I don't want it before the template due to a code organization issue.

Comment: Did you remove `inline` when you did that?

Comment: Yes, I removed `inline`.

Comment: Your problem is not overload resolution, but name lookup (the second overload is not found). Consider changing/adding this to the question title and tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem of dependent name lookup.

In the expression `overloaded(value);`, the name `overloaded` is dependent as per [temp.dep]/1.

As far as I know, in the expression `n::overloaded(value)`, the name `overloaded` (in the *id-expression* `n::overloaded`) is **not** dependent.

---

Dependent name lookup is very peculiar, [temp.dep.res]/1

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context and from the definition context.

(There's a point of instantiation for function templates at the end of the file, so all declarations from associated namespaces can be found.)

For non-dependent names, the normal lookup rules apply (lookup from the definition context).

Therefore, to find names declared *after* the definition of the template, they have to be dependent *and* be found via ADL.

---

A simple workaround is to introduce another parameter to the function `overloaded` or wrap the argument, such that one of the arguments of this function has namespace `n` associated:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {};

namespace n {
  struct ADL_helper {};
  inline void overloaded(int, ADL_helper = {})
  { std::cout << "n::overloaded(int,..)" << std::endl; }
}

template<typename T> void try_it(T value) {
  overloaded(value, n::ADL_helper{});
}

namespace n {
  inline void overloaded(C, ADL_helper = {})
  { std::cout << "n::overloaded(C,..)" << std::endl; }
}

int main()
{
  try_it(1);
  C c;
  try_it(c);
}
```

alternatively:

```
namespace n {
  template < typename T >
  struct wrapper { T elem; };

  inline void overloaded(wrapper<int>)
  { std::cout << "n::overloaded(wrapper<int>)" << std::endl; }
}

template<typename T> void try_it(T value) {
  overloaded(n::wrapper<T>{value});
}

namespace n {
  inline void overloaded(wrapper<C>)
  { std::cout << "n::overloaded(wrapper<C>)" << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now. I chose to go the route of using a function outside the namespace just because it is going to be more maintainable in my circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

HUGE EDIT from original version where I mistakenly thought that the call was a non-dependent name.

OK, let's try to break this down.

The second example works, because even in the non-template case you'd expect things to work normally with all the overloads declared before the use.

The first version works because of 14.6.4.2/1:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the
>   function name is an unqualified-id but not a templateid, the candidate
>   functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except
>   that:
>
> — For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup
>   (3.4.1), only function declarations with external linkage from the
>   template definition context are found.
>
> — For the part of the lookup
>   using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations with
>   external linkage found in either the template definition context or
>   the template instantiation context are found.

We're interested specifically in the first part `if the function name is an unqualified-id` and the second bullet `found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.` So we learn that if the name is unqualified, names visible at thepoint of instantiation are added to the set of candidates.

Likewise in the third case, your name is fully-qualified, thus *inhibiting* the use of candidates visible at the point of instantiation and instead falling back only on candidates at the point of definition.

If you were to move `c` into `n`, add `using namespace n;` into the `try` function, and remove the `n::` from the function call you would find that ADL would once again pick up the overload and all would be happy.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Because the global namespace is associated with the class `C` in that case.

Comment: Interestingly, there's been a change between C++03 and C++11 here (14.6.4.2/1), leaving out the "external linkage" part; this probably makes it redundant with [temp.dep.res]/1